# SQL get perticuler name arranged in the middle of query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column fruits and it has rows like

```
banana
pineapple
orange
grapes
apple
mango
pomegranate
Kiwi
grapefruit
peach
```

or maybe like this

```
 pineapple
 grapefruit
 orange
 grapes
 apple
 mango
 pomegranate
 Kiwi
 banana
 peach
```

I want to retrieve all that with `grapefruit` in the middle all the time like following no matter whether it has even or odd number of rows

```
banana
pineapple
orange
grapes
grapefruit
apple
pomegranate
Kiwi
mango
```

I know basic SQL query `SELECT fruit FROM FRUITTABLE`
but dont know further

Comment: I cannot think why you would want to do this, but thats not what SQL does

Comment: You could sort ascending or descending, but that does not seem to be what you want to do either

Comment: @RiggsFolly asc or desc wont help

Comment: I don't get it. You need X previous and next rows around `grapefruit` row, or you just want to select a couple of records and to put `grapefruit` in the middle afterwards?

Comment: @mitkosoft I want grapefruit in the middle like it has 9 rows then it stays on 5th and if it has 10 rows then on 5th or 6th position, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can order by `is_even/is_odd` on some enumeration. (here: the difference in  `row_number()` over *nothing*)

---

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE fruits(fruit text);
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit) VALUES
('banana') ,('pineapple') ,('orange') ,('grapes') ,('apple') ,('mango') ,('pomegranate') ,('Kiwi') ,('grapefruit') ,('peach')
        ;

with numbered AS (
        select fruit, row_number() OVER () rn
        FROM fruits
        )
, gnum AS (
        SELECT rn FROM numbered
        WHERE fruit = 'grapefruit'
        )
SELECT n.fruit, n.rn
FROM numbered n
JOIN gnum g ON true
ORDER BY ((n.rn - g.rn) %2), (n.rn <> g.rn)
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
    fruit    | rn 
-------------+----
 mango       |  6
 grapes      |  4
 Kiwi        |  8
 pineapple   |  2
 grapefruit  |  9
 banana      |  1
 orange      |  3
 apple       |  5
 pomegranate |  7
 peach       | 10
(10 rows)
```

---

Edit: the tie-breaker is not always correct (caused by modulo on negative numbers) A better order would be

---

```
ORDER BY (ABS(n.rn - g.rn) %2) , (n.rn <> g.rn) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explain why you want to do this, maybe there is a better way to do obtain the result you want.

But I think that you could add a weight col in your table 
and order by that value in the select.
Just take into consideration that whenever you add a new row you have to update that weights in order to maintain grapefruit in the middle.
And you have to define how to manage the pair numbers of rows.

[Table with examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZqqb.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruits
ORDER BY Weight;
```

Comment: the idea is appreciated well actually rows are created automatically so cant give them weight

Comment: You can add weight in the insert:
INSERT INTO Fruits VALUES
('strawberry', CASE WHEN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
Fruits WHERE Weight = 1) >
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
Fruits WHERE Weight = 3) THEN 3 ELSE 1 END)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
(select * from fruit where id < (select max(id)/2 from fruit))
union select * from fruit where id = grapefruit
union
(select * from fruit where id > (select max(id)/2 from fruit))
```

Or something like that. If you don't have an id you might have to use rownumber, but it should be doable.

Comment: probably it's better to use the ID of `grapefruit` itself in first and last `select` with some `limit`, rather than `max(id)`?